# Does return type of method matter when it comes to overloading?

Tags: types, return, overloading

here is a method- int someMethod(int a). is float someMethod(int a, int b) is overloaded version of 1st method or it is different method?

Answer (score 2):

In most languages, the return type of a method is not considered to be part of its "signature", and thus doesn't enter into questions of overloading. In all languages I can think of where the question makes sense, yes, these are overloads.